# When the progress is 100% that automatically reposition the background

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a progressbar in jquery, I need when it reaches 100% reposition the background to:

```
background-position: -33px -1px;
```

the problem that this background this in another div, not this in the progressbar:

[image]

jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/G2dbn/

Comment: Can you show us more code?

Comment: I guess I don't the question without context of HTML/CSS.  Sounds to me like you just need to do a better job of conceptualized and producing the images if you want the progress bar to go all the way to the end of the progress meter.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/G2dbn/

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a callback on `.animate()` to reposition your background?

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```
function progress(percent, $element) {
    var progressBarWidth = percent * $element.width() / 100;
    $element.find('div').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, 500, callbackFunction).html(percent + "%&nbsp;" + "<span></span>");
}
```